# Vue.js IE 11 logout routing problems

Tags: vuejs2, internet-explorer-11, vue-router

I'm testing my Vue project's logout function and it works like a charm on Chrome and Firefox. On IE 11, navigating to:

> localhost:8081/#/logout

causes a lot of issues. User is logged out but logout page keeps refreshing and refreshing.

Logout code in my router:

```
    {
        path: '/logout',
        name: 'Logout',
        component: Logout
    },
```

Any tip how to solve this IE 11 issue?

Comment: What logic do you use to logout a user? Is it removing a token? If so, you can tell IE to stop updating once there is no token.

Comment: Try to check the console for any error or warning message may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: It might be routing problem because typing http://localhost:8081/#/home and pressing enter does not react. I have to press refresh arrow in URL window and then I'm navigated to /home.

Comment: Looks like your app is hosted under IIS. I suggest you to check whether you have any URL routing rules set in IIS which causing the issue.

Comment: Hash change in IE gives the bug. I found this post https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/3740423/

Comment: As Microsoft had already stop providing new updates for IE. So I think this issue will not be fixed for IE. If your users are able to use MS Edge than you can suggest them to move to MS Edge. If they are not using Win 10 OS than soon Microsoft will launch the new Edge chromium which may help to fix the issue.  Ref: https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/